What's an Example of an Invertible Incomputable Function?
I had the following question on a computability exam:

Given $2$ incomputable functions $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, must $f \circ g$ be incomputable?

I reasoned that without loss of generality, let $f = g^{-1}$ and therefore $f \circ g = \text{identity}$, which is computable, hence disproving the claim. However, I could not think of any concrete examples, so I could not prove my reasoning.

You don’t need a concrete example to prove your reasoning. There are an uncountable number of bijective functions and only countably many computable functions.

You don't need $g$ to be a bijection; only an injection. Then let $f(n) = g^{-1}(n)$ if $n$ is in the range of $g$, and set it to $0$ otherwise.

@spaceisdarkgreen Can you derive a proof of how the existence of a bijective invertible function is implied by there being an uncountable number of bijective functions and only countably many computable functions? I still do not understand why.

@AmitBashan bijective and invertible are the same thing. (And it looks like you understood the rest in your comment under my answer.)

You don't need a concrete example to prove this. Here a simple counting argument suffices: the number of invertible functions $\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ is uncountable, whereas the number of computable functions is countable.
One other thing you need to verify though is that if $g$ is non-computable, so is $g^{-1}.$ But that follows from the fact that you can compute $g(n)$ from $g^{-1}$ just by searching for the $m$ such that $g^{-1}(m)= n.$
But if we want an explicit example, note that as Polygon mentions in the comments, you really only need an injective non-computable function for a counterexample. One example is just a modification of the halting function: let $g(e)$ be $2e$ if $\Phi_e(e)$ halts and $2e+1$ if $\Phi_e(e)$ does not halt. (And for the other part of the argument, you can compute $g$ from its "inverse" by the same idea as above... the only minor difference is you need to hard-code $g(0)$, as $0$ is the only number that the "inverse" maps many-one to).
(And if we really want a bijective function, just put indices in groups of $4$ (or some $n$ where $n!>2^n$) and let $g$ permute the indices within a group in such a way as to encode the halting pattern for the group.)

So, if the set of invertible functions is uncountable, namely A, and the set of computable functions is countable, namely B, the set A - B, which is the set of invertible and non-computable functions must be non-empty which proves their existence?

@AmitBashan yes
